# MySQL query string for selecting certain row with a id

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL db, and I needed to know what query should I use for selecting the row whith the ID I tell it:

An example row:

```
TITLE: test
DATE: 01/01/01 01:01
CONTENT: test content
ID: 5
```

How would I query it so I tell MySQL to give me the row which has the ID `5`? Thanks :D

Comment: select * from table where id = 5;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TITLE, DATE, CONTENT FROM TABLE WHERE ID=5
```